# Recursively find and open files

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to search through all subdirectories and files to find files with a specific extension. When I find a file with the extension, I need to open it, find a specific string from within the file and store it within a txt file.

This is what I have so far for finding all of the correct files:

```
find . -name ".ext" ! -path './ExcludeThis*'
```

This is what I have for opening the file and getting the part of the file I want and storing it:

```
LINE=$(head .ext | grep search_string)
SUBSTR=$(echo $LINE | cut -f2 -d '"')
echo $SUBSTR >> results.txt
```

I am struggling for how to combine the 2 together, I have looked at 'for f in **/*' and then run an if statement in there to see if it matches the .ext and remove the need for find all together but **/* seems to work on directories only and not files.

A break down of any solutions would be very much appreciated too, I am new to shell scripting. Thanks.

Comment: `**/*` should work ... did you have `globstar` enabled? (i.e. `shopt -s globstar`)

Comment: There is no reason to break that second bit up into three statements like that. A single pipeline will work just fine.

Comment: find ... | while read filename; do grep search_string $filename | cut ... >>results.txt; done

Comment: @mpez0, ...which needs to be more paranoid to work with interesting filenames (ones with backslash-escape sequences in the names, or spaces, or wildcard expressions, etc).

Comment: @mpez0, find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do ... "$filename" ... would be closer to something robustly constructed.

Comment: ...also, GNU grep's NUL delimiter support is relevant if trying to get the corner cases right.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your points are quite correct, but for the OP who is "new to shell scripting", they add significant complexity to understanding basic scripting

Comment: @mpez0, that's true. I'm a firm believer that it's better to have a visibly steep learning curve than to have the great bulk of practitioners **unknowingly** writing bad code, but thinking they're doing everything right. Deciding to do things slapdash as a conscious decision is a different matter, but having slapshod approaches held up as ideal is something I have trouble countenancing, whatever the audience.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find -name "*.ext" \! -path './ExcludeThis*' -exec head -q '{}' \+ | 
    grep search_string | cut -f2 -d'"' >> results.txt
```

---

### [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) explanation

```
find -name "*.ext" \! -path './ExcludeThis*' -exec head -q '{}' \+
```

For each file name matched, executes `head` (with `\+`, the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end, so *the total number of invocations of the command will be much less than the number of matched files*).

Notice I replaced `.ext` with `*.ext` (the first way just math a file named exactly `.ext`), and `!` with `\!` (protection from interpretation by the shell).

The [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head) option `-q` is necessary because that command prints headers when used with multiple files (due to `\+` in this case).

In addition, if no path is given, the default is taken (`.`). i.e.: `find . -name` = `find -name`.

---

### pipeline explanation

```
<find ... -exec head> | grep search_string | cut -f2 -d'"' >> results.txt
```

- While `head` write the lines (10 by default) for every file in the pipe, `grep` read them.
- If `grep` matches `search_string` in some of them, write those lines in the next pipe.
- At the same time, `cut` take the second fields (delimited by `"`) of every line and appends them in `results.txt`

Comment: This worked for me, needed root access as it was saying complaining that: find 'head' terminated by signal 13. Thank you for your breakdown too, it explained everything very well for me